# Find all occurrences of a file (by name) and replace them by selected file

Tags: windows-7, linux, file-management

So I have some javascript and PHP classes I use when making webpages. They contain some general functions one might need, like translation management, benchmarking and so on.

Over time, I'm improving the classes as I find bugs or I need to add new features. The classes are copied all over my `/htdocs` XAMPP directories wherever they're needed.

I want to copy the newest versions of classes from `/htdocs/classes` to `/htdocs/*/ including subdirectories. Long story short, I want to seek file duplicates by names and replace by the newest version.

How would you that on Windows?
Could you eventually also include a Linux answer I might need in near future?

Comment: "How would you that on Windows?" Since `/htdocs/classes`matches `/htdocs/*/`, I'd say "very carefully". Other than that, any scripting language of your choice will be able to take care of this, and also work on Linux.

Comment: Well, I'm sure *some* (which is a subset of *any*) scripting languages can do that. I wouldn't ask if I thought it's impossible. I'm aware of the overwrite risk and I'd definitely back-up before playing around.